# How to enable https in Ray serve Framework

Tags: ray, serve

Currently, I could connect to Ray serve backend via HTTP, but I could not found any suggestion about how to enable https.

```
ray.init(address="auto", namespace="serve")
    serve.start(
        detached=True,
        http_options={
                "host": "0.0.0.0",
                "port": 443,
                "middlewares": [ Middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=["*"], allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"])]
            }        
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting it in front of reverse proxy like nginx, apache, traefik, etc. You can technically give uvicorn the https certs file but in generally it's not a recommended pattern.